# Geolocation and jQuery - Can't post results using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm currently working on a project to make a location-aware site.  In essence, the user comes to the page, and their location is found using the HTML5 method and then using jQuery, the location is posted to a page which saves the location/address to a codeigniter session, but if they want to update their location, or change to a different location(IE they want to use their work address as the location instead of their present address), theres a jQuery colorbox that displays and lets them type in a custom address.

Everything works flawlessly to get the initial location, but when I try and get the updated location saved, I receive the error "**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'lat'**" which then Google Chrome references as being an error not in jQuery, but in the file for Google Maps API.  Any suggestions?

```
jQuery('.inputsubmit').click(function() {

//Takes values from user submitted fields and parses them into an address string
var street = jQuery('.inputaddress').val();
var city = jQuery('.inputcity').val();
var state = jQuery('.inputstate').val();


var address = street +" "+ city +", " +state;

   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   var geocoderresult= geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
           var newlocation = results[0].geometry.location;

               //Posts coordinates and address string to a CodeIgniter function to update users session information
               jQuery.post("somepage", {location: newlocation, address: address},function(data) {
             alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
           });

       } else {
          alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
       }
    });

});
```

I've tried everything I can think of to get the post to work.  All of the code works up till the point, and I've commented out the post line and everything works correctly. This is one of our main website's features, to provide instant and quick results based off of location.

Thanks!

Comment: which line of the posted javascript code causes the error? Chrome's inspector should tell you this

Comment: Line 12 of the main.js of the map api file

Comment: @matt b - its happening within the Google Maps API. "Google Chrome references as being an error not in jQuery, but in the file for Google Maps API". This typically means you passed a parameter to the API that the API was not expecting. Debug this by confirming the values of the parameters you are passing into the API.

Comment: Yeah in my code I have an alert box display each value through each step of the function.  All thats going to the API is the address the user enters, and it does return the correct coordinates, its not until the jQuery.post tries running that it breaks

Comment: what kind of data is "somepage" returning? is "somepage" on the same domain/subdomain/port as the current page?

Comment: Somepage posts to a codeigniter controller function. Its on the same domain/server. It's the same function used to same the original location data, and as far as what its returning, it shouldn't return anything, I just have the callback setup for debugging purposes to see if there are any errors occurring on the model/controller side

Comment: try this for debugging: `$.ajaxSetup({error: function(){console.log(arguments);}});`

Comment: Instead of posting `location: newlocation`, maybe you should split up the data? `lat: newlocation.lat, lng: newlocation.lng`

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to have your Google API code loaded on `somepage` in addition the original page . Because the `$.POST` can't find the `lat` object it seems the geolocation.js file isn't included on `somepage`.